# There is any "Podman Compose"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, podman

I recently found out about Podman (https://podman.io). Having a way to use Linux fork processes instead of a Daemon and not having to run using root just got my attention.

But I'm very used to orchestrate the containers running on my machine (in production we use kubernetes) using docker-compose. And I truly like it.

So I'm trying to replace docker-compose. I will try to keep docker-compose and using podman as an alias to docker as Podman uses the same syntax as docker:

> alias docker=podman

Will it work? Can you suggest any other tool? I really intend to keep my docker-compose.yml file, if possible.

Comment: i expect a lot of new answers in the future as podman evolves

Comment: We could probably use "dnf install podman-docker" in RHEL8 to emulate docker and then use docker-compose as explained here https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-docker-compose

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, that is doable now, check [podman-compose](https://github.com/muayyad-alsadi/podman-compose), this is one way of doing it, another way is to convert the docker-compose yaml file to a kubernetes deployment using [Kompose](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/). there is a blog post from  [Jérôme Petazzoni @jpetazzo: from docker-compose to kubernetes deployment](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2019/01/22/docker-compose-kubernetes-1-en/)

Comment: Thank you @walid! Quite new this one. But it seems to do the trick. Kompose it's helpful as well. Adopting kubernetes as the "de facto" standard helps you move faster into production. I'll try both. Best regards!

Comment: Hello, @otaviofcs I have added Jérôme Petazzoni blog reference. I hope these are enough to get you going ;-)

Comment: Note that there are many docker-compose commands which are incompatible with podman-compose, which is unfortunate: https://github.com/containers/podman-compose/issues

Comment: true @RégisB. however for simple cases, you might just use podman, check out latest article regarding moving from compose to podman https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/compose-podman-pods

Answer (score 11):

**Update 6 May 2022** : *Podman now supports Docker Compose v2.2 and higher* (see [Podman 4.1.0 release notes](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/tag/v4.1.0))

Old answer:

##### Running docker-compose with Podman as a normal user (rootless)

Requirement: Podman version >= 3.2.1 (released in June 2021)

1. Install the executable **docker-compose**

   ```
   curl -sL -o ~/docker-compose https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)
   chmod 755 ~/docker-compose
   ```

   Alternatively you could also run **docker-compose** in a container image (see below).
2. Run

   ```
   systemctl --user start podman.socket
   ```
3. Set the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST`

   ```
   export DOCKER_HOST=unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock
   ```
4. Run

   ```
   ~/docker-compose up -d
   ```

##### Running docker-compose with Podman as root

Requirement: Podman version >= 3.0 (released in February 2021)

Follow the same procedure but remove the flag `--user`

```
systemctl start podman.socket
```

##### Running docker-compose in a container image

Use the container image **docker.io/docker/compose** to run
**docker-compose**

```
podman \
 run \
  --rm \
  --detach \
  --env DOCKER_HOST=unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock \
  --security-opt label=disable \
  --volume $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock:$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock \
  --volume $(pwd):$(pwd) \
  --workdir $(pwd) \
  docker.io/docker/compose \
   --verbose \
   up -d
```

(the flag `--verbose` is optional)

The same command with short command-line options on a single line:

```
podman run --rm -d -e DOCKER_HOST=unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock --security-opt label=disable -v $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock:$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock -v $(pwd):$(pwd) -w $(pwd) docker.io/docker/compose --verbose up -d
```

**Regarding SELINUX**: Runnng Podman with SELINUX is preferable from a security point-of-view, but I didn't get it to work on a Fedora 34 computer so I disabled SELINUX by adding the command-line option

`--security-opt label=disable`

### Troubleshooting tips

##### Test the Docker REST API

A minimal check to see that the Docker REST API is working:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --unix-socket $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock \
    http://localhost/_ping
OK$
```

##### Avoid short container image names

If any of your *docker-compose.yaml* or *Dockerfile* files contain a short container image name, for instance

```
$ grep image: docker-compose.yaml
    image: mysql:8.0.19
$
```

```
$ grep FROM Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9
$
```

edit the files to use the whole container image name instead

```
$ grep image: docker-compose.yaml
    image: docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.19
$
```

```
$ grep FROM Dockerfile
FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9
$
```

Most often short names have been used to reference [DockerHub Official Images](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_images/)
(a [catalogue](https://hub.docker.com/u/library)) so a good guess would be to prepend the container image name with `docker.io/library/`

There are currently many different container image registries, not just DockerHub (docker.io). Writing the whole container image name is thus a good practice. Podman might complain otherwise depending on how Podman is configured.

##### Rootless users can't bind to ports below 1024

If for instance

```
$ grep -A1 ports: docker-compose.yml
    ports:
      - 80:80
$
```

edit *docker-compose.yaml* so that the host port number >= 1024, for instance *8080*

```
$ grep -A1 ports: docker-compose.yml
    ports:
      - 8080:80
$
```

An alternative solution is to adjust *net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start* with `sysctl` (see [*Shortcomings of Rootless Podman*](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/master/rootless.md))

##### In case Systemd is missing

Most Linux distributions use Systemd where you would preferably start the Podman service (providing the REST API) by "starting" the Podman socket

```
systemctl --user start podman.socket
```

or

```
systemctl start podman.socket
```

but in case Systemd is missing you could also start the Podman service directly

```
podman system service --time 0 unix:/some/path/podman.sock
```

Systemd gives the extra benefit that the Podman service is started on demand with Systemd socket activation and stops after some time of inactivity.

##### Caveat: Swarm functionality is missing

A difference to Docker is that the functionality relating to Swarm is not supported when using docker-compose with Podman.

References:

- https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-docker-compose
- https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/10644#discussioncomment-857897

Comment: Thank you for improving the answer. When can update when it's production ready

Comment: Well, I think it is a drawback to be required to run podman in root mode to support docker-compose. Why didn't redhat continue investing on podman-compose?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure Podman is installed on your machine.
2. You can install Podman Compose in a terminal with the following command:

```
pip3 install https://github.com/containers/podman-compose/archive/devel.tar.gz
```

3. `cd` into the directory your docker-compose file is located in
4. Run `podman-compose up`

See the following [link](https://fedoramagazine.org/manage-containers-with-podman-compose/) for a decent introduction.