# Run multiple podman containers, like docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, podman

I found some library that can replace **docker-compose** in **podman** but it is still under development, so my question is how can I run multiple container together, currently I am using my bash script to run all but it is good just for the first time not updating the container.

I'd prefer at first if there is any way in **podman** rather than using some other tool.

library (under development) --> https://github.com/muayyad-alsadi/podman-compose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is any "Podman Compose"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55154393/there-is-any-podman-compose)

Comment: actually it is not, as i mentioned that library is under development. either I need replacement or official way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Kubernetes Pod concept](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods) is what you're looking for, or at least it allows you to *run multiple containers together* by following a well-established standard.

My first approach was like you, to do everything as a command to see it working, something like:

```sh
# Create a pod, publishing port 8080/TCP from internal 80/TCP
$ podman pod create \
  --name my-pod \
  --publish 8080:80/TCP \
  --publish 8113:113/TCP

# Create a first container inside the pod
$ podman run --detach \
  --pod my-pod \
  --name cont1-name \
  --env MY_VAR="my val" \
  nginxdemos/hello

# Create a second container inside the pod
$ podman run --detach \
  --pod my-pod \
  --name cont2-name \
  --env MY_VAR="my val" \
  greboid/nullidentd

# Check by
$ podman container ls; podman pod ls
```

Now that you have a pod, you can export it as a Pod manifest by using `podman generate kube my-pod > my-pod.yaml`.

As soon as you try your own examples, you will see how not everything is exported as you would expect (like networks or volumes), but at least it serves you as a base where you can continue to work.

Assuming the same example, in a YAML Pod manifest, it looks like this `my-pod.yaml`:

```yaml
# Created with podman-2.2.1
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-pod
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  # Create the first container: Dummy identd server on 113/TCP
  - name: cont2-name
    image: docker.io/greboid/nullidentd:latest
    command: [ "/usr/sbin/inetd", "-i" ]
    env:
    - name: MY_VAR
      value: my val
    # Ensure not to overlap other 'containerPort' values within this pod
    ports:
    - containerPort: 113
      hostPort: 8113
      protocol: TCP
    workingDir: /
  # Create a second container.
  - name: cont1-name
    image: docker.io/nginxdemos/hello:latest
    command: [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
    env:
    - name: MY_VAR
      value: my val
    # Ensure not to overlap other 'containerPort' values within this pod
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      hostPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    workingDir: /
  restartPolicy: Never
status: {}
```

When this file is used like this:

```sh
# Use a Kubernetes-compatible Pod manifest to create and run a pod
$ podman play kube my-pod.yaml

# Check
$ podman container ls; podman pod ls

# Output
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS            PORTS                                        NAMES
1a53a5c0f076  docker.io/nginxdemos/hello:latest    nginx -g daemon o...  8 seconds ago   Up 6 seconds ago  0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8113->113/tcp  my-pod-cont1-name
351065b66b55  docker.io/greboid/nullidentd:latest  /usr/sbin/inetd -...  10 seconds ago  Up 6 seconds ago  0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8113->113/tcp  my-pod-cont2-name
e61c68752e35  k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2                                       14 seconds ago  Up 7 seconds ago  0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8113->113/tcp  b586ca581129-infra
POD ID        NAME    STATUS   CREATED         INFRA ID      # OF CONTAINERS
b586ca581129  my-pod  Running  14 seconds ago  e61c68752e35  3
```

You will be able to access the 'Hello World' served by nginx at 8080, and the dummy identd server at 8113.