# Docker-compose with podman?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, podman

How i use docker-composer file in podman?

This examples:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  gitea:
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    environment:
      - DB_TYPE=postgres
      - DB_HOST=db:5432
      - DB_NAME=
      - DB_USER=
      - DB_PASSWD=
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - git_data:/data
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Generate image using dockerfile normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upcoming Podman 3.0 supports the Docker REST API well enough to be used as back-end for docker-compose. It is planned to be released in a few weeks (see [Podman releases](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases)).

Caveats:

- Running Podman as root is supported, but not yet running as a normal user, i.e. running "rootless". (See [feature request](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/9169))
- Functionality relating to Swarm is not supported

To enable Podman as the back-end for docker-compose, run

```
 sudo systemctl enable --now podman.socket
```

Podman will then listen on the UNIX domain socket */var/run/docker.sock*

See also: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69339693/10964962)

1. Ensure podman is installed on your machine.
2. In a terminal, install podman compose with the following command:

```
pip3 install https://github.com/containers/podman-compose/archive/devel.tar.gz
```

3. cd into the directory your docker-compose file is located in
4. Run `podman-compose up`

See the following [link](https://fedoramagazine.org/manage-containers-with-podman-compose/) for a decent introduction