# docker-compose error Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: linux, docker-compose, podman

Operating system AlmaLinux 8.3

When I try to run docker-compose I get errors but my docker commands execute fine

> docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace
> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

> docker version
> Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
> Client:       Podman Engine
> Version:      4.2.0
> API Version:  4.2.0
> Go Version:   go1.18.9
> Built:        Tue Feb 21 09:53:16 2023
> OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

My system can't find the docker service

> systemctl start docker
> Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service not found.

I can run docker commands normally

> ```
> $ docker run hello-world
> Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
> Hello Podman World ...!
>
>          .--"--.
>        / -     - \
>       / (O)   (O) \
>    ~~~| -=(,Y,)=- |
>     .---. /`  \   |~~
> o  o \~~~~.----. ~~
>   | =(X)= |~  / (O (O) \
>    ~~~~~~~  ~| =(Y_)=-  |
> U      |~~
>
> Project:   https://github.com/containers/podman
> Website:   https://podman.io
> Documents: https://docs.podman.io
> Twitter:   @Podman_io
> ```

I hope to start the docker process through service docker start

I expect docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace to work

Comment: Because you are indeed not running Docker but Podman, which emulates Docker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-compose with podman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65999569/docker-compose-with-podman)