# How to run a Docker Compose file in Ubuntu system which has Podman as the Container Engine

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, podman

I know that we need to install the `podman-docker` package from RPM to use Docker Compose in Redhat systems.

But such a package is not available on the **Ubuntu** system in the APT. Then how can I run a Docker Compose file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package **podman-docker** is not used when running **docker-compose** together with **Podman**.
.

##### Some notes about the RPM package *podman-docker*

The RPM package *podman-docker* provides a wrapper shell script so that
executing `docker` will actually execute `podman`.

```
$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 34 (Thirty Four)
$ rpm -ql podman-docker | grep bin
/usr/bin/docker
$ file /usr/bin/docker 
/usr/bin/docker: a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
$ cat /usr/bin/docker
#!/usr/bin/sh
[ -f /etc/containers/nodocker ] || \
echo "Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg." >&2
exec /usr/bin/podman "$@"
$
```

This functionality is not needed when running **docker-compose** with Podman.  Instead the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST` is used to configure what
backend **docker-compose** will connect to. Podman understands the Docker REST API and can be used as a backend for **docker-compose**.

##### Running **docker-compose** with Podman on Ubuntu

(Untested instructions as I don't have an Ubuntu system)

1. Install the executable **docker-compose**

   ```
   curl -sL -o ~/docker-compose https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)
   chmod 755 ~/docker-compose
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   systemctl --user start podman.socket
   ```

   (Remove `--user` when running as root)
3. Set the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST`

   ```
   export DOCKER_HOST=unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/podman/podman.sock
   ```
4. Run

   ```
   ~/docker-compose up -d
   ```

You could also skip installing the `docker-compose` executable and
instead run `docker-compose` in the container **docker.io/docker/compose**

For more details see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65670037/757777

Ubuntu 21.04 has Podman 3.0.1.
The package contains this list of files: https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/podman/filelist

For instance

- /lib/systemd/system/podman.service
- /lib/systemd/system/podman.socket
- /usr/lib/systemd/user/podman.service
- /usr/lib/systemd/user/podman.socket

These files are needed for
`systemctl --user start podman.socket`
and
`systemctl start podman.socket`
to work.

Note, Podman 3.0.1 only supports docker-compose when Podman is run as root.

The coming release Ubuntu 21.10 scheduled for October 2021 currently contains Podman 3.2.1.
Podman 3.2.1 supports running docker-compose when Podman is run as a normal user (i.e. running rootless).

I would guess that 21.10 will be a safer bet to get Podman working with docker-compose.  An alternative could be to install a newer Podman version from the 3rd party repository Kubic.

https://podman.io/getting-started/installation

Comment: Go through this too: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-docker-compose