# podman – how to install fuse-overlay fs on alma linux 9 – podman 4.2.0

Tags: security, cloud, fuse, podman

I tried this script: [How to install and setup WordPress using Podman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74054932/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-using-podman)

on Alma linux

with  podman version 4.2.0

I am stuck with an error

```
ERRO\[0000\] Unmounting /home/bryan/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/22b8d2bb0766ffdfcad3b6440bcbdfa39ddfd4019f054959f9e55e18d8f4e52e/merged: invalid argument

Error: building local pause image: error mounting new
container: error mounting build container
"9a258f8cc8ed88cd4f5c829c4903ba122bc8d2072d71bab006c3160aae008e6e": 
creating overlay mount to /home/bryan/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/
22b8d2bb0766ffdfcad3b6440bcbdfa39ddfd4019f054959f9e55e18d8f4e52e/merged,
mount_data="lowerdir=/home/bryan/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/22b8d2bb0766ffdfcad3b6440bcbdfa39ddfd4019f054959f9e55e18d8f4e52e/empty,upperdir=/home/bryan/.local/share/containers/storage/
overlay/22b8d2bb0766ffdfcad3b6440bcbdfa39ddfd4019f054959f9e55e18d8f4e52e/diff,workdir=/home/bryan/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/22b8d2bb0766ffdfcad3b6440bcbdfa39ddfd4019f054959f9e55e18d8f4e52e/work,,volatile": using mount program /usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs: fuse: device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first

fuse-overlayfs: cannot mount: No such file or directory

: exit status 1

Error: no pod with name or ID gcl_wp_mdb found: no such pod

Error: no pod with name or ID gcl_wp_mdb found: no such pod
```